# Perl Fork Manager

Tags: perl

I am starting Perl forkmanager with limit to 4 processes but it starts more like 8 processes. So how can I control how many processes get started? (I want first 4 to finish then starts another 4 like that): my Code looks like this

```
opendir($par_dir,$parent);

while( my $sub_folders = readdir($par_dir)){
  if ($sub_folders =~ /^..?$/){next;}
  my $path = $parent. '/'.$sub_folders;
  next unless ( -d $path);
  opendir ( $sub_dir,$path);

  while ( my $file =readdir($sub_dir)){

     next unless $file =~ /\.bai?$/i;

     my $destdir = $outdir;

     $pm-> start() and next;
     $pm->set_max_procs(MAX_CHILDREN);
     mkdir( $destdir, 0777 );
     system("do something with the $file);

  }
  $pm ->finish();
  closedir($sub_dir);

}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3A%3AForkManager)?  It helps if you give a link (the permalink on CPAN is good) to the package you're using.  Many people will not have come across it as it is just one of 25,000 packages on CPAN.

Note that the synopsis for Parallel::ForkManager says:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

$pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($MAX_PROCESSES);
```

So, did you specify 4 as the argument when you created your `$pm` handle?